# how to convert int8 array to binary and extract bits in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, binary, 2d

I have a huge numpy 2D array with int8 values and i would like to convert it to binary values, extracting one or more bits and construct a new array without loops using only methods from numpy or libraries like this (such as `numpy.where` or `np.bitwise_and`).

For example :

```py
array1 = [4, 128]
array_bits = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
#or ...
array_bits = ['00000100', '10000000']
#Extracting bit number 3 :
array_res = [1, 0]
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of what you have tried already. We can better help you if you have a specific problem. This is not merely a code production factory. Please read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to better understand how a question should be asked!

Comment: As i said i have no idea how to do it without looping ... I can make an easy loop over each value but it will takes 30 minutes or more .. That's why i have to find a solution without using loops.

Comment: likely when you call other methods say of numpy under the hood they will be looping over the data....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [`np.unpackbits`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html#numpy.unpackbits) to help out with this. For this function to work, we need to cast the data to `np.uint8` first.

```
>>> lst = [4, 128]
>>> arr = np.array(lst, dtype=np.uint8)
>>> bits = np.unpackbits(arr)
>>> bits
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

Now to access the "3rd" bit we will use index 5 since there are 8 bits in a byte and you want the 3rd to last. Then use a step of 8 to continue getting the next value's bit at the same position.

```
>>> bits[5::8]
array([1, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why you don't want to use loops (and honestly I can't think of a way you would do it *without* looping), but here's what I was able to find.

Assuming a 2D array of int8s:

```
nums = numpy.array([[random.randrange(255) for _ in range(20)],
                    [random.randrange(255) for _ in range(20)]], dtype=numpy.int8)

# Produces
array([[  27, -111,   79, -116, -114,   59,  -12,  -44,  -65,   66,   89,
        -116,    0,   15,  -31,   55,   54, -115,  115,   57],
       [  72,  -57,  -20,  -88,  -94, -112,  -40,   55,   47,  120,  125,
        -101,  117,  -35,  -29,  -41,  -68,  -76,  -11,  -67]], dtype=int8)
```

You can use the [`numpy.ndarray.tostring`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html) method to convert this to a bytearray:

```
>>> nums.tostring()
b'\x1b\x91O\x8c\x8e;\xf4\xd4\xbfBY\x8c\x00\x0f\xe176\x8ds9H\xc7\xec\xa8\xa2\x90\xd87/x}\x9bu\xdd\xe3\xd7\xbc\xb4\xf5\xbd'
```

and then you can use some formatting (and a loop) to convert that into a list of binary strings:

```
>>> bin_strs = [f'{b:08b}' for b in nums.tostring()]
# bin_strs
['00011011',
 '10010001',
 '01001111',
 '10001100',
 '10001110',
 '00111011',
 ...
 ]
```

then from *that*, you can use slicing and int-casting to get specific bits, although you'll have to index backwards since the 0th bit is on the right end:

```
>>> third_bits = [int(s[-3]) for s in bin_strs]
[0,
 0,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 0,
 ...
 ]
```

Granted the result isn't 2D, but you didn't mention that as being important.